# HtmlDocument not loading all html

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am attempting to parse the html of a web page but htmlAgilityPack is not loading all the html correctly

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.politico.com/2016-election/results/map/president/florida/");

List<HtmlNode> nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//article").ToList();
```

The first 9 nodes load correctly and allow me to further parse them but once I get beyond the 9th node it does not load the full inner html or inner text. Essentially I am looking to get the name of each county and how many votes each candidate got in each county but it only works for the first 9